# Understanding shared match of 1,177 cM?

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, relationship-analysis, half-siblings

I recently received a "DNA Match" on my account to some one who shows 1,177 cM shared.  I am trying to understand what this is really telling me.

This is important to me as I do not know who my Father is but suspect I have a whole set of half siblings from his side.

I know who my mother was and have met my 1/2 siblings from her marriage to their Father, hence knowing my niece as stated below.

I have another post that shows 810 cM shared and that individual is my niece by my half sister.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! Please take a moment to look over the site -- we have MANY questions already which discuss the numbers of cMs shared with matches, and the references given there should be of help in answering your question. Don't be alarmed if your question is closed as a duplicate. You can learn more about how this site works by using the [help].

Answer (score 0):

As [commented by @MarshallClow](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/15810/understanding-shared-match-of-1-177-cm#comment24858_15810):

> [DNA Painter](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/1177) suggests
> that "Half Aunt / Uncle - Half Niece / Nephew" are likely, with half
> sibling less likely, but still possible.

The range given by [DNA Painter](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/1177) for half siblings is 1160 – 2436 cM which your value of 1177 is only just inside.

Your "niece by [your] half sister" is near the middle of the range of 500 – 1446 suggested for a half niece/nephew by [DNA Painter](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/810).